# Error send multiple emails, should send one only

Tags: php, sql, sendmail

Hi guys I need some help...

I have a litle php script that check if database is true, if it is call other php and send an email, if not does nothing.
It works, but he check the database and if it found 3 or more trues, he send 3 or more emails :S
Today i found out 1700+/- mails to read.
Can you help me just send one email?

Thanks

```
<?php

include'database.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM on_form_9 WHERE dias = '0'";
$diferencial_tempo = "UPDATE on_form_9 SET dias = DATEDIFF (actualizacao, NOW())";

if ($conn->query($diferencial_tempo) === TRUE) {
    echo "DATA OK";
  echo( " --- ");
} else {
    echo "DATA ERRO" . $conn->error;
}

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    include'baterias_email.php';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 e-mails enviados";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: What do you think to do with other "true" records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED, DIDNT KNOW HOW THIS ESCAPE ME LOL

```
if ($conn->query($diferencial_tempo) === TRUE) {
    echo "DATA OK";
    include'baterias_email.php';
} else {
    echo "DATA ERRO" . $conn->error;
}
```

Delete de rest :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code in the following way. Since I don't now what baterias_email.php does you might change that script in order to get the data from your database processed as you need. You will have all rows in the array `$result`.

```
<?php

include'database.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$now = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM on_form_9 WHERE dias = '0'";
$diferencial_tempo = "UPDATE on_form_9 SET dias = DATEDIFF (actualizacao, NOW())";

$sendEMail = false;
$result = [];
if ($conn->query($diferencial_tempo) === TRUE) {
    echo "DATA OK";
  echo( " --- ");
} else {
    echo "DATA ERRO" . $conn->error;
}

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    //collect the data you need here and set a flag
                    $result[] = $row;
                    $sendEMail = true;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 e-mails enviados";
}


if ($sendEMail === true){
    //change your baterias_email.php in order to use the array of rows $result if you need the data
    include 'baterias_email.php';
}
$conn->close();
```

I hope that helps

Comment: hi thanks for the help, I didnt test cuz I found out the way like 5 minuts after I post.
But thanks for the help :)